# How to configure VIM and ALE for AVR programming?

Tags: vim

I use [VIM](https://www.vim.org) and [ALE](https://github.com/dense-analysis/ale) for C programming on desktop and on AVR embedded.

Desktop programming works because ALE picks up the system compiler automatically, but it does not work properly for AVR programming because there is a [separate toolchain](https://github.com/osx-cross/homebrew-avr) I must use. Typical errors I see would be it's inability to find include files, for instance:

```
#include <avr/io.h>        /* Not found */
#include <util/delay.h>.   /* Not found */

int main(void) {
  while(1) {}
  return 0;
}
```

Is it possible to configure ALE and my projects so that ALE is able to automatically pick up the right compiler settings?